# How many binary numbers length of 17 exists (with extra conditions)

Tags: combinatorics

How many binary numbers exists (x1,x2,...x17), length of "vector" is 17,
that are "LESS" than (x2,x3,...x17,1).
LESS means xi <= yi for any i from 1 to 17.

I tried to do it myself, my idea is to find numbers that are more and then substract from all numbers:
for example consider (x1,x2,x3,x4,x5) and (x2,x3,x4,x5,1)
if x2 = 1 and x1 = 0 with whatever other set to and we move it to right:
(0 1 x3 x4 x5)
2^8
(x1 0 1 x4 x5)
2^8
(x1 x2 0 1 x5)
2^8
(x1 x3 x3 1 0)
2^8
then:
4*(2^8) = 32
all possible numbers:
2^5 = 32
then:
32 - 32 = 0.
I understand that numbers are repeated, but how to take into account that?

Comment: It seems this is not about "binary numbers" but "binary tuples", no?

Comment: As a suggestion, try the same problem for smaller lengths.  That way you;'ll be able to list all the cases explicitly.

Comment: Please use MathJax.

Comment: @Card_Trick Sorry, I m new here.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are asking for the number of *binary tuples*, $(x_1,x_2 \cdots x_{17})$ such that $x_i \le x_{i+1}$ for $i=1\cdots 16$

If so, then you tuple must be of the form $(0,0 \cdots0,0,1,1\cdots 1)$ that is, $n$ zeroes followed by $m$ ones, with $n+m=17$ and $n\ge0$, $m\ge 0$. Then the answer is 18.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. Consider these numbers: (x1=0,x2=1, ... x17=0) or (1,1,... 1) or (0,0,0,0...0). Maybe I got you wrong at some point... Can you give me more detailed explanation please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider these numbers: (x1=1,x2=0,x3=1 ... x17=1). So the answer is 18 + 15 = 33?

Comment: It's hard to answer your questions if you don't get your terminology consistent. I  don't even know what you call "a number". My answer assumed that your question ("how many numbers...") considered each binary _tuple_ (or _vector_) "a number". If you disagree (as your comments seem to imply), then you can ignore this (and then, BTW, I cannot make sense of the question)